# Query to get results for every hour of the day even data if not present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the query for getting the count of users every hour of day in the table. If the data for that hour is not present, I want to record the hour with count of zero. Also users should be counted only for their first entry. Subsequent entries should be ignored.

Table:

```
userId      creationDate
1           2014-10-08 14:33:20.763
2           2014-10-09 04:24:14.283
3           2014-10-10 18:34:26.260
```

Desired output:

```
Date                      UserCount
2014-10-08 00:00:00.000      1
2014-10-08 01:00:00.000      1
2014-10-08 02:00:00.000      1
2014-10-08 03:00:00.000      0
2014-10-08 04:00:00.000      1
....
.....
2014-10-10 23:00:00.000      1
2014-10-10 00:00:00.000      0
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(creationDate as date) AS ForDate, 
    DATEPART(hour, date) AS OnHour, 
    COUNT(distinct userId) AS Totals
FROM 
    Table
WHERE
    primaryKey = 123
GROUP BY 
    CAST(creationDate as date), DATEPART(hour, createDate)
```

This only gives me per hour for the record that is present. Not the data for the missing hours. I think there is a way by using a cross join to get 0 data even for the missing hours.

Something like this, I came across, but not able to construct a proper query with it.

```
cross join (select 
                ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
            from 
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS) hours 
where hours.seqnum >= 24
```

Once again, I am not a SQL expert, but trying hard to construct this result set.

One more attempt :

```
with dh as (
     select DATEADD(hour, seqnum - 1, thedatehour ) as DateHour 
     from (select distinct cast(cast(createDate as DATE) as datetime) as thedatehour
           from Table a 
          ) a 
          cross join
          (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
           from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          ) hours
          where hours.seqnum (less than)= 24
    )
select dh.DateHour, COUNT(distinct c.userId) 
from dh cross join Table c
--on dh.DateHour = c.createDate
group by dh.DateHour
order by 1
```

Comment: couldn't you do something along the lines of `INT DEFAULT 0;` on the end?

Comment: Exactly where on the end means ?

Comment: it would be a setting for the row in the table you're saving the count to, easiest to edit within phpmyadmin if you have it installed

Comment: Is the range only 1 day (24 hours)? Is the date a user input/parameter?

Comment: The range could be one day or not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build up a table of possible hours, and then join this to your actual records.

The best way to build up a table of possible hours is to use a recursive common table expression.
Here's how:

```
-- Example data
DECLARE @users TABLE(UserID INT, creationDate DATETIME)
INSERT @users
        ( UserID, creationDate )
VALUES  ( 1, '2014-10-08 14:33:20.763'),
        (  2, '2014-10-09 04:24:14.283'),
         ( 3, '2014-10-10 18:34:26.260')


;WITH u1st AS (  -- determine the FIRST time the user appears
    SELECT UserID, MIN(creationDate) AS creationDate
    FROM @users
    GROUP BY UserID
),  hrs AS ( -- recursive CTE of start hours
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CAST(creationDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME) AS [StartHour] 
    FROM @users AS u
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 1, [StartHour]) AS [StartHour] FROM hrs 
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,[StartHour]) < 23
), uGrp AS ( -- your data grouped by start hour
    SELECT -- note that DATETIMEFROMPARTS is only in SQL Server 2012 and later
        DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CreationDate),MONTH(CreationDate), 
                     DAY(creationDate),DATEPART(HOUR, creationDate),0,0,0) 
                     AS StartHour, 
        COUNT(1) AS UserCount  FROM u1st AS u
    GROUP BY YEAR(creationDate), MONTH(creationDate), DAY(creationDate), 
             DATEPART(HOUR, creationDate)
)
SELECT hrs.StartHour, ISNULL(uGrp.UserCount, 0) AS UserCount 
FROM hrs LEFT JOIN uGrp ON hrs.StartHour = uGrp.StartHour
ORDER BY hrs.StartHour
```

NB - DATETIMEFROMPARTS is only in SQL SERVER 2012 and greater. If you are using an earlier version of SQL SERVER you could have

```
WITH u1st AS ( -- determine the FIRST time the user appears
    SELECT UserID, MIN(creationDate) AS creationDate
    FROM @users
    GROUP BY UserID
),  hrs AS ( -- recursive CTE of start hours
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CAST(creationDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME) AS [StartHour] 
    FROM @users AS u
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 1, [StartHour]) AS [StartHour] FROM hrs 
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,[StartHour]) < 23
), uGrp AS ( -- your data grouped by start hour
    SELECT -- note that DATETIMEFROMPARTS is only in SQL Server 2012 and later
        CAST(CAST(YEAR(creationDate) AS CHAR(4)) + '-'
             + RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(creationDate) AS CHAR(2)), 2) + '-'
             + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(creationDate) AS CHAR(2)), 2) + ' '
             + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, creationDate) AS CHAR(2)), 2) 
             + ':00:00.000'
             AS DATETIME) AS StartHour,
        COUNT(1) AS UserCount  FROM u1st AS u
    GROUP BY YEAR(creationDate), MONTH(creationDate), DAY(creationDate), 
             DATEPART(HOUR,creationDate)
)
SELECT hrs.StartHour, ISNULL(uGrp.UserCount, 0) AS UserCount 
FROM hrs LEFT JOIN uGrp ON hrs.StartHour = uGrp.StartHour
ORDER BY hrs.StartHour
```

Comment: The group by in the uGrp messes up the count

Comment: Not 100% sure its right THB I just copied that bit from your question. If you want a more certain grouping you should maybe change to `GROUP BY YEAR(creationDate), MONTH(creationDate), DAY(creationDate), HOUR(creationDate)` and change the select to `SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(creationDate),MONTH(creationDate),DAY(creationDate),HOUR(creationDate),0,0,0) AS [StartHour]` (this function is in SQL Server 2012 and beyond) I'll adjust the answer

Comment: In what way is the count messed up? What are you verifying it against?

Comment: So I am using distinct with the count, when I do the query only for a particular hour I get different count and when I use the above query I get different count for that particular hour.

Comment: Well looking at your original question again I notice you `COUNT(DISTINCT(userID))` instead of `COUNT(1)` as I have it. Try swapping it in. If this sorts it this must mean you have duplicate users in the table though! I'll change the answer to include that

Comment: Case I am talking about is when user1 has an entry in say 20:00 PM and also has entries in 21:00 then with COUNT(DISTINCT(userID))  and the above queries he will have two entries for both time periods. Where right way would be to have entry for only the first time period. If he has entry there he should not be considered for the time periods occurring afterwards.

Comment: Something like this maybe ? 
AND userId IN (
    select userId, min(DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(hour, createDate),
CAST(CAST(createDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))) as createDate
    from MyTable
    WHERE primaryId = 123 AND createDate <> 'given Date'
    group by userId
)

Comment: oh OK @BigShow - you didn't make it clear that you'd get multiple entries per userID at differing times (and you were only interested in the first per user). I've edited the answer to include another CTE that groups the table to determine the first entry for every user. Hopefully thats what you're looking for

Comment: yes you are right, I discovered this as I came across count issue. Thank you very much for this !

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question on dba just this morning...https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86435/filling-in-date-holes-in-grouped-by-date-sql-data.
You can used my GetSequence function, or create a Numbers table.  I haven't done my own testing yet to validate what was suggested in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**BUILD SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable(
    userId          INT,
    creationDate    DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO yourTable VALUES (1, '2014-10-08 14:33:20.763'), (2, '2014-10-09 04:24:14.283'),(3, '2014-10-10 18:34:26.260');
```

## SOLUTION

```
WITH tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(23) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM sys.columns
)
,hourly(creationDate) AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, t.N, d.creationDate)
    FROM tally t
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, creationDate), 0) AS creationDate FROM yourTable
    ) d
)
SELECT
    h.creationDate,
    userCount = ISNULL(t.userCount, 0)
FROM hourly h
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        creationDate = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, creationDate) ,DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, creationDate), 0)),
        userCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, creationDate), 0), DATEPART(HOUR, creationDate)
)t
    ON t.creationDate = h.creationDate
```

**CLEANUP**

```
DROP TABLE yourTable
```

Comment: The group by in the left join query messes up the count

Answer (score 1):

1. **Create a temporary table (let's say `#CreationDateHours`) containing create date and hours from 0 to 23.**

   ```
   Declare @date as date
   SELECT MAX(CAST(creationDate as date)) AS ForDate, 0 as OnHour into #CreationDateHours
       FROM Table
           WHERE
              primaryKey = 123
       Select @date=ForDate from #CreationDateHours 
       Declare @i int
       Set @i=1
       While @i<24
       begin
       insert into #CreationDateHours
       select @date as ForDate, @i as OnHour 
       set @i+=1
       end
   ```
2. **Now, Run this query to get the desired results**

   ```
   select t1.ForDate, t1.OnHour, isnull(t2.Totals,0) AS Totals
   from
       #CreationDateHours t1 left join (SELECT 
           CAST(creationDate as date) AS ForDate, 
           DATEPART(hour, date) AS OnHour, 
           COUNT(distinct userId) AS Totals
       FROM 
           Table
       WHERE
           primaryKey = 123
       GROUP BY 
           CAST(creationDate as date), DATEPART(hour, createDate)) as t2
   on t1.ForDate= t2.ForDate and t1.OnHour=t2.OnHour
   ```

Comment: I could not format the sql code using ctrl+K. Can anyone edit my post to do the necessary formatting.

Comment: The group by in the left join query messes up the count

Comment: It should not, because left join would only convert null values in t2.Totals to zero. It would not change the values which you already have.

Answer (score -1):

```
select count, strftime('%H', creationDate) as hour from table group by hour;
```

OUTUPUT:

```
count         hour
n1              01
n2              02
n3              03
...             ...
n24             24
```

Tested on SQLite3
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html
you can see all the formats
(like %d for every day of month)
if you want the whole date
strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H, creationDate)

Comment: This solution does not account for the different dates and accounts for the hours only.

Comment: Yes. That's why is the explanation below the code for different formats