# SQL - placing values in date bucket

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, bucket

Really struggling with this as a SQL newb, so i need to place values from the is_registered column into hourly buckets based on the time of day they were created. The below is a small sample

| creation date | is_registered |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-28 00:03:12.240 | 1 |
| 2021-10-28 00:09:16.221 | 1 |
| 2021-10-28 00:12:23.234 | 1 |
| 2021-10-29 00:03:19.240 | 1 |
| 2021-10-29 00:48:12:190 | 1 |
| 2021-10-29 01:09:36:129 | 1 |
| 2021-10-29 01:29:29:120 | 1 |

The result I would like to acheive (with the full dataset) is the following(buckets for each hour of the day

| Date | Hour Bucket | Total in each bucket |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-28 | 00:00-01:00 | 289 |
| 2021-10-28 | 01:00-02:00 | 876 |
| -------- | -------------- | ------------- |
| 2021-10-29 | 00:00-01:00 | 190 |
| 2021-10-29 | 01:00-02:00 | 309 |

And so on.

Hope thats as enough information provided, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: So if a row is "registered" at 1:00, does it count in both of the first 2 output rows? This is a common mistake to think of 1 hour as running from 0:0:0 to 1:0:0 (61 minutes).

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer, if registered at 12:59, it will floor to 12:00 so be 00:00-01:00
reg at 01:00:19 will be 01:00-02:00

Comment: [Refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539381/query-to-get-results-for-every-hour-of-the-day-even-data-if-not-present)

Answer (score 0):

Try following way

```
    --Create table script

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_4](
    [creationdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [isreg] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

    --Sample data
    
    insert into table_4 values (getdate(),1)
    insert into table_4 values (getdate()-1,1)
    go
    
    
    -- query
    WITH report(N) AS(
        SELECT TOP(23) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM sys.columns
    )
    ,hourly(creationdate) AS(
        SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, t.N, d.creationdate)
        FROM report t
        CROSS JOIN(
            SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, creationdate), 0) AS creationdate FROM table_4
        ) d
    )
    SELECT
       convert(date, h.creationdate) as [Creation date],
       convert(varchar(5), DATEPART(HOUR, h.creationdate)-1)+ ' - ' + convert(varchar(5),DATEPART(HOUR, h.creationdate)) as [Hour Bucket], 
        [Total in each bucket] = ISNULL(t.isreg, 0)
    FROM hourly h
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT
            creationdate = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, creationdate) ,DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, creationdate), 0)),
            isreg = COUNT(*)
        FROM table_4
        GROUP BY DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, creationdate), 0), DATEPART(HOUR, creationdate)
    )t
        ON t.creationdate = h.creationdate
        order by h.creationdate
```

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539381/query-to-get-results-for-every-hour-of-the-day-even-data-if-not-present)

Comment: Thank you Malvik, why is it required to create a table and insert sample data?

Comment: I have added an answer with my sample data. if you have the same structure then not required to create that table and insert sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Using this tvf may be more maintainable:
[DateRange TVF](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/a-daterange-table-valued-function)

```
 WITH Ranges
 AS
 (
    SELECT [Value] AS date_from
        ,LEAD([Value]) OVER (ORDER BY [Value]) AS date_to
        ,CAST([Value] AS date) AS [Date]
        ,CONVERT(char(5), [Value], 14) + '-'
            + CONVERT(char(5), LEAD([Value]) OVER (ORDER BY [Value]), 14) AS Hour_Bucket
    FROM dbo.DateRange('2021-10-28', '2021-10-30', 'hh', 1)
)
SELECT R.[Date], R.Hour_Bucket
    ,COUNT(T.is_registered) AS Total_Registered
FROM Ranges R
    LEFT JOIN YourTable T
        ON T.creation_date >= R.date_from
            AND T.creation_date < R.date_to
            AND T.is_registered = 1
WHERE R.date_to IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY R.[Date], R.Hour_Bucket
ORDER BY [Date], Hour_Bucket;
```